# Java Script scroll top with transition duration

Tags: javascript

this is my function. i cant find how to add transition duration in it. it just takes me straight upto top. syntax is what i'm looking for. idk much about js.

```
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop=0 ;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop =0 ;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to learn CSS (transitions), or some library like jQuery to do what you want with a transition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery…) scroll to top animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)

Comment: i know css good @JaromandaX. what i dont know is how to embed it in js. in my function. because it's what scrolling it to the top of my page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross browser JavaScript (not jQuery...) scroll to top animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation)

Comment: actually, I don't think CSS transitions apply, sorry

Comment: document.getElementById("myDIV").style.transitionDuration = "1s"; 
.animate would be a possible solution but how do i write it? it doesnt work

Comment: @KamranHashmi check this [add transition duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607147/how-do-i-get-the-webkit-transition-duration-property-with-jquery) but you need to use jquery

Answer (score 3):

Try using this in place of your function:

```
window.scrollTo({
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Answer (score 1):

You can add transition duration by using below code.

```
function topFunction() {
  currentYOffset = self.pageYOffset;
  initYOffset = currentYOffset;

  var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
  currentYOffset -= initYOffset*0.05; 
  document.body.scrollTop = currentYOffset ;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = currentYOffset;

    if(self.pageYOffset == 0){
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, 20);

}
```

You can set smoothness of the transition by editing the value of interval. I have set it as 20.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery solution, using the [jQuery.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

The function gives you the ability to change the animation time, as well as the selector on which the animation is being applied, so that you can scroll other elements, too.

```
/**
 * Scroll to a given point on the page with animation
 *
 * @param {int} scrollValue - The top position to scroll to
 * @param {int} [animationTime] - Speed of the animation (in milliseconds)
 * @param {string} [selector] - Which element to scroll. By default, it is the html/body
 */
function animateScrollTo(scrollValue, animationTime, selector){
    if(typeof animationTime === "undefined"){
        animationTime = 520;
    }


    if(typeof selector === "undefined"){
        selector = "html, body";
    }

    jQuery(selector).animate({scrollTop: scrollValue}, animationTime);
}
```

Comment: Not a jquery question :/

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Just use this property and `document.getElementById('some-id').scrollTop = 0` will work with smooth transition/animation.

Comment: When does this work? It doesn't seem to help when I do this, not even in Chrome

Comment: this is exactly how it was working for me
`document.getElementById('chat-content').scrollTop = 0`